# How to unscheduled/inactive Saved Search after refreshing sandbox account Netsuite?

Tags: refresh, netsuite, sandbox, saved-searches

After refresh sandbox account from production account , some scheduled saved search who are made to run on production account run on sandbox and it's not what I want.

There is a way to prevent this ?

Saved search are not an accessible record so I don't Know how to do with a script or a workflow. Maybe a general preference or a rule or setting during the refreshing exist but I didn't find it .

Comment: Saved searches are accessible. You can do a saved search for saved searches, you can load a saved search definition and you can modify it and save it back.

Comment: How can I see the different fields and theirs ID possible for the "Search" record

Comment: problem, when I try to load the record  I have the following error {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INVALID_RCRD_TYPE"}

Comment: With SS2.x you use the `n/search` module to work with searches and not the `n/record` module.

Comment: I tried this : var searchRec = record.load({
              type: search.Type.SAVED_SEARCH,
              id: result.id,
              isDynamic: false
            });

Comment: Read the help on the `N/search` module. There are also script examples help topic for it. It has simple search.load() and search.save() you can use if you know the id.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found except delete all the schedule searchs is to set an
unreachable filters to get 0 results

if someone have a better solution please let me know

```
function execute(scriptContext) {
        var searchSavedSearch = search.create({
            type: search.Type.SAV , filters: {
                name: 'sendscheduledemails',
                operator: search.Operator.IS,
                values: ['T']
            }
        })
        var searchResult = searchSavedSearch.run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 })
        var resultNumber = searchResult.length
        for (var x = 0; x < resultNumber; x++) {
            var searchRecord = search.load({ type: search.Type.SAVED_SEARCH, id: searchSavedsearch[x].id })
            var filtersArr = searchRecord.filters
            filtersArr.push(search.createFilter({
                name: 'internalid',
                operator: search.Operator.IS,
                values: -1
            }))
         searchRecord.save()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set email delivery preferences for you Sandbox account?  If not go to Setup > Company > Email > Email Preferences (Administrator).  Choose your preference on the Sandbox and Release Preview subtab, under Sandbox Options.  Reference [Suite Answer Id: 20152](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20152/kw/sandbox%20email%20preferences)